Stack Overflow | Borders on every UI element
There is nothing really to say about it; the screenshots are explaining it by themselves.
It looks like an active CSS Debugging.
The bug has existing since weeks/months. 
iOS 17.5 (I updated today). 
Using in browser, Edge version 124.0.2478.89
No matter if I’m logged in or not.
The bug seems to only happening on stackoverflow.com and their subdomains. Because Stack Exchange is looking normal.


Sounds like a workaround is to disable Edge's forced Dark Mode and instead rely on SO's native dark mode: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/429844/951830

This is, frankly, a bug in Edge's forced dark mode. There might be things which SE can do to avoid the bug, and they should look into doing so, because others like you will blame SO, but it's really a problem in Edge's implementation of their dark mode. The issue should be reported to MS/Edge development.

@Makyen I just asked Is the forced dark mode flag in Chromium-based browsers supported? earlier today.

The bug is not on SE side, so it's off topic here.

@ShadowWizardLoveZelda There's an argument, theoretically, to be made that it's on-topic, since forced dark mode is a built-in feature of a supported browser rather than a separate extension.

@Sonic but unless that feature is on by default, I don't think SE should support it. If one wants such features awesome, but it should be clear that websites can't be expected to support all of those fancy features. And can't help but mention that IE/Edge (which are the same just different name) are very much famous for exactly such bugs.
